# Recommend books/resources for this stack: linux, lighttpd, postgres, webpy

Tags: linux, python, postgresql, lighttpd

I'm trying to learn to run a simple server (and python simultaneously, but that's beside the point). The tutorials available at the websites of the aforementioned technologies were enough to get the thing running, but that doesn't mean I know what I'm doing or know how to keep it running.

The advantage is that I don't care if I break something, because the server is virtual. I have no problem starting from scratch to do it right if that's what it takes. I have no existing applications or data to worry about migrating.

Anyway, what are some good resources for learning more? If there's a great website/blog/podcast, great. If there's a great book, perhaps better since books tend to go into more detail. If there's any chance of finding something that specifically discusses this stack (aside from the webpy website), then well... that'll just make my day.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use and suggest.
For linux the best recommendation would be "Linux Administration Handbook" by Evi Nemeth.
For Python the best recommendation would be "Dive Into Python" by Mark Pilgrim.

Refer this thread for books for linux:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143184/which-book-would-you-recommend-for-a-linux-sysadmin

Refer this thread for python:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570/what-is-the-best-quick-read-python-book-out-there

Comment: +1 for dive into python -- Mark makes learning python a giddy, fun experience for a variety of experience levels, but with a practical bent.  Plus you can download it for free.

Answer (score 0):

**Python**

- [Thinking in Python](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIPython) by Bruce Eckel
- Most of the Reilly books on Python are good - but you should at them yourself first to see what specifically each have to offer.
- Also I think you should read reviews on Amazon - I almost never buy a book without reading the Amazon page for it first.